# Set custom messages for post update/save

Tags: updates, save-post

I am trying to make a custom message instead of the default message when i save a post, does anybody know how to do it!

Comment: It’s not yet okay. Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 9):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
example:

```
    //add filter to ensure the text Book, or book, is displayed when user updates a book 
add_filter('post_updated_messages', 'codex_book_updated_messages');
function codex_book_updated_messages( $messages ) {
  global $post, $post_ID;

  $messages['book'] = array(
    0 => '', // Unused. Messages start at index 1.
    1 => sprintf( __('Book updated. <a href="%s">View book</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
    2 => __('Custom field updated.'),
    3 => __('Custom field deleted.'),
    4 => __('Book updated.'),
    /* translators: %s: date and time of the revision */
    5 => isset($_GET['revision']) ? sprintf( __('Book restored to revision from %s'), wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
    6 => sprintf( __('Book published. <a href="%s">View book</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
    7 => __('Book saved.'),
    8 => sprintf( __('Book submitted. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview book</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
    9 => sprintf( __('Book scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>. <a target="_blank" href="%2$s">Preview book</a>'),
      // translators: Publish box date format, see http://php.net/date
      date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i' ), strtotime( $post->post_date ) ), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
    10 => sprintf( __('Book draft updated. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview book</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
  );

  return $messages;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Message Storage

The `'message'` part of the `$_GET` array is what is responsible for holding the actual message value as `integer`. This means that everything that gets passed in there, will be set as actual message. The messages itself are stored inside a global array in the Admin UI templates. It's named `$messages` and has three keys per default:

1. `page`
2. `post`
3. `attachment`

The messages are stored as sub-arrays of the main `$messages` array.

## Notes:

Some things to keep in mind (WP core v4.0.1):

- The `0` is not in use.
- The `attachment` messages currently are a hack and just have the string `'Media attachment updated.'` on every key.
- All message sub-arrays are 10 keys long

## How to add custom messages

Use the `post_updated_messages` filter:

```
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', function( $messages )
{
    $messages['post'][2] = 'My awesome custom field just updated. Congratulations!';
    return $messages;
} );
```

Look at `~/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php` for which message is used for what.

> The fallback, if no post type is used, is the `post` post type messages array.

## Custom Post Types

You can safely add your own set of messages via a callback on the bespoken filter. Just make sure that you use your custom post types name as key for the messages array:

```
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', function( $messages )
{
    $messages['my_custom_post_type'][2] = 'Go, buy some milk!';
    return $messages;
} );
```

The callback itself probably is best hooked on

```
do_action( "load-{$pagenow}" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought this might help some.

After going through length and breadth of various sites I could only get a custom message displayed with help from this.

https://onextrapixel.com/10-tips-for-a-deeply-customised-wordpress-admin-area/

```
function frl_on_save_post($post_id, $post) {/* add warning filter when saving post */

    if($post->post_type == 'post') //test for something real here       
        add_filter('redirect_post_location', 'frl_custom_warning_filter');

}
add_action('save_post', 'frl_on_save_post', 2, 2);

function frl_custom_warning_filter($location) { /* filter redirect location to add warning parameter*/

    $location = add_query_arg(array('warning'=>'my_warning'), $location);
    return $location;
}

function frl_warning_in_notice() { /* print warning message */

    if(!isset($_REQUEST['warning']) || empty($_REQUEST['warning']))
        return;

    $warnum = trim($_REQUEST['warning']);

    /* possible warnings codes and messages */                 
    $warnings = array(
        'my_warning' => __('This is my truly custom warning!', 'frl')
    );

    if(!isset($warnings[$warnum]))
        return; 

    echo '<div class="error message"><p><strong>';
    echo $warnings[$warnum];
    echo '</strong></p></div>';
}       
add_action('admin_notices', 'frl_warning_in_notice');
```