# what is correct way to hook when update post

Tags: php, hooks, actions, save-post

i try to hook when post is updated but all hook i try never executed except `updated_post_meta`

```
add_action('updated_post_meta', 'my_function');

function my_function($post_id) {    
    echo 'This is my post ID : '.$post_id;
}
```

I've tried this `add_action('save_post', 'my_function');` but no id was echo out, or maybe this message already echo but never renders because of redirect header is sent.

Comment: you have a space after `save_post`, is that a typo here, or was that in your original code? also, [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) while developing.

Comment: @Milo sorry typo, but not in original code

Comment: if that's the case, then you should see your output in the top left corner of the screen when creating a new post. saving an existing post happens before a redirect, so you won't see anything unless you have debugging enabled.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

When a post is updated there are some hooks that are fired:

- **`'pre_post_update'`** is an action fired just **before** the post is updated, the argument passed are 2: `$post_ID` and `$data` that is an array of **all** the other database colums of the post table
- **`'transition_post_status'`** is an hook fired on update, and pass 3 arguments: $new_post_status, `$old_post_status` and `$post` (object).
- Then, there are other 2 transition hooks fired, but they are dynamic named, it means that the effective action fired depends on the old and the new post status.
  **`"{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}"`** and **`"{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}"`**. First pass the only the post object as argument, the second pass the post id and the post object. Find documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions).
- **`'edit_post'`** that pass 2 arguments: `$post_ID` and `$post` (object)
- **`'post_updated'`** that pass 3 arguments: `$post_ID`, `$post_after` (post object after the  update), `$post_before` (post object before the update)
- Another dynamic hook: **`"save_post_{$post->post_type}"`** that depends on post type, e.g. for standard posts is `'save_post_post'` and for pages is `'save_post_page'`, this hook pass 3 arguments: `$post_ID`, `$post` (object) and `$update` that is a boolean (true or false) that is true when you perform an update, in fact this hook is fired also when a post is saved for first time.
- **'`save_post`'** that is fired both on update and on first saving, and pass the same 3 arguments of the previous hook.
- **'`save_post_{$post_type}`'** that is fired both on update and on first saving, and pass the same first 2 arguments of the previous hook.
- Finally you have **'`wp_insert_post`'**, that is fired both on update and on first saving, and pass the same 3 arguments of the previous 2 hooks.

These hook are fired every time a post is updated, both via admin pages in backend and via when updated "manually" using [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) or [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) functions.

When the post is updated using admin pages there are additional hooks fired, an example is **`'update_post_redirect'`** or **`'post_updated_messages'`**. (See [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59118/35541) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/29254/35541)  WPSE answers for usage examples).

Note that if you want make use of some hooks argument, that isn't the first, one you have to explicitly declare it in `add_action` call.

E.g. if you want to use the `'$update'` argument (that is the 3rd) of the `'save_post'` hook you need to add `3` as `$accepted_args` param on `add_action` ([see docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)):

```
// if you don't add 3 as as 4th argument, this will not work as expected
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post_function', 10, 3 );

function my_save_post_function( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
  $msg = 'Is this un update? ';
  $msg .= $update ? 'Yes.' : 'No.';
  wp_die( $msg );
}
```

Last note regard *timing*: you must be sure that `add_action` is called *before* the action is triggered, or it will do nothing.

E.g. this code:

```
wp_update_post( $post );
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_function', 10, 3 );
```

will do nothing, because the action is added after the hook is fired. Here is simple to recognize it, in real world code isn't always so.

Comment: I think that the 'save_post' action hook is also fired when hitting Add New (Post, Page, CPT) in the dashboard. To see yourself just run this code. `function save_post_test( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
 print ' post_id : ';
 var_export( $post_id );

 print ' post : ';
 var_export( $post );

 print ' update : ';
 var_export( $update );

 wp_die( 'save_post hook runs when you click Add New..' );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_post_test', 10, 3 );`
Why does the 'save_post' action run on Add New instead of on Publish? To make the auto-draft post I suppose.

Comment: @lowtechsun Like it is said in the A, the hooks are fired every time a post is updated, i.e. saved in DB. When you hit "Add New", close to page loading, WP creates a draft post stored in DB so he hooks are fired.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. Just found out about this yesterday and thought the concept of this is confusing. Meaning first I open the page to add a new post. At this stage I thought I have _not_ already created a post. Only _once_ I hit Publish I would think the new post is created. Taking this further I hope WP does delete the auto-draft post _if_ I hit Add New but then leave the page without hitting Publish?

Answer (score 3):

Why not hook in `post_updated_messages`. That way you can show this message just like the default wordpress post updated.

```
add_filter('post_updated_messages', 'your_message');

function your_message(){
}
```

Look for an example here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

under `post_updated_messages`