# Custom Post Type action on post update

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks

I'm trying to trigger a specific action when a custom post type that I've created is created/updated.

Ideally, I could run the same function/process of whether the post is:

- Created using the New Post screen in the WP Admin
- Updated using the Edit Post screen in the WP Admin
- Updated using the Bulk Edit function that I've created
- Updated using a Quick Edit

I've reviewed and experimented a bit with:

- `save_post_{custom_post_type}`
- `pre_post_update`
- `handle_bulk_actions-edit-{custom_post_type}`

The `save_post` hook would work except on a bulk update it appears it only gets called once with one post.

The `handle_bulk_actions-edit` would work and I can iterate over the IDs provided but that excludes editing posts manually on the post edit screen, etc.

I also looked at `update_{$meta_type}_metadata` as that hooks on specific metadata fields, but that seems like a hack given I really need it on the post level.

Is there one hook that gets called on ANY post add/edit that I can use regardless of the source of the edit (post edit screen, bulk edit, quick edit)?  Or what is the best way to handle it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is correct way to hook when update post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134664/what-is-correct-way-to-hook-when-update-post)

Comment: That answer doesn't address bulk post edits using handle_bulk_actions-edit-{custom_post_type}.  It seems that when you hook into handle_bulk_actions-edit the save_post is only fired on the last post in the list of IDs.