# How to keep a CPT from being visible on the front end?

Tags: custom-post-types

Here's how I define the CPT:

```
$args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => FALSE,
        'show_ui' => TRUE,
        'capability_type' => SNG_CAP_SUPPORT,
        'hierarchical' => FALSE,
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 
            'editor'
        ),
        'menu_icon' => SNG_PLUGIN_URL . '/images/admin-support.png',
        'rewrite' => FALSE,
        'has_archive' => FALSE );
    register_post_type( SNG_SUPPORT_POSTTYPE, $args );
```

Basically when a user creates a post of this post_type there's a success message that says "view this post" which leads to the front end of my site *mysite.com/?sng-support=test-8*. I want to remove this message and link but I'm not looking for a CSS fix. There *MUST* be a way to make this work? I tried playing with the args and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Essentially I don't want the posts to be accessible from the URL or the front end unless I specifically query for them.

I appreciate any help! :)

Comment: can you prevent `single.php` from showing posts of that type?

Comment: I guess I could redirect to the front page if the post type of the main query matches but I figured that there must be a way to do this within the definition. I guess I might be wrong.

Comment: not sure there's anything that will remove that link, it'll just 404 if you set `publicly_queryable` to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that at least part of what you want is to [alter the submission update messages](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L33), probably in addition to @toscho's code.

```
function kill_message($messages) {
  global $post_type;
//   var_dump($messages); die;
  if ('your-cpt-slug' == $post_type) {
    // alter your message strings
  }
  return $messages;
}
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'kill_message' );
```

If you `var_dump` the `$messages` variable it is pretty obvious what the messages represent. Just rewrite them however you want.

Comment: Thanks this will help take out the link but that specific filter only works for the update message. I can't find the post_added_messages (or something of the sort) in the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference ... Any idea what the filter name is?

Comment: I'm a dink, it's all in the same filter. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17885/set-custom-messages-for-post-update-save

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug: [#17609 'View post' link shown even when post type can't be viewed on the front-end](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17609).

To fix it, filter `get_sample_permalink_html` and test the post type properties:

```
add_filter( 'get_sample_permalink_html', function( $html, $post_id )
{
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
    $object    = get_post_type_object( $post_type );

    if ( $object->public && $object->publicly_queryable )
        return $html;

    add_filter( 'get_shortlink', function( $shortlink, $id ) use ( $post_id )
    {
        return $id == $post_id ? '' : $shortlink;
    }, 10, 2 );

    return '';

}, 10, 2 );
```