# How can I set a dynamic value for post_updated_messages based on return value of post_updated?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, actions

I'm familiar with [how to set custom messages for post updates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17885/set-custom-messages-for-post-update-save) using the `post_updated_messages` action hook. This question is slightly different.

I have a function/action hook on `post_updated`:

```
function my_custom_function($post_id) {
  $response = ping_other_service_and_get_confirmation($post_id);
  syslog(LOG_INFO, 'Response:' . $response['body']);
  return $response['body'];
}
add_action( 'post_updated', 'my_custom_function');
```

Assuming that the `ping_other_service_and_get_confirmation()` function pings some other web service, letting it know that the post has been updated, and returns a confirmation message as a string. Right now I'm logging that string to the system logs, which is fine for development, but I need to use that string inside the post updates message for clients to be able to see the confirmation. How can I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: I guess I could maybe save the response value as a custom field on the post, and then query that in the `post_updated_messages` filter function, but that seems messy, it's a transitory message, it really shouldn't be stored in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution using query vars to pass the status message to the next page so that it can be used in `post_updated_messages`. Here's a simplified version of what I did, with all the function names changed for simplicity's sake to focus on the problem at hand;

First, added the value I needed to the `$_POST` var;

```
function my_custom_function($post_id) {
  $response = ping_other_service_and_get_confirmation($post_id);
  $_POST['status_response'] = $response['body'];
}
add_action( 'post_updated', 'my_custom_function');
```

Then, when that value is set, I redirect the post edit page to the same URL with a query string added that has the value I need;

```
function pass_status_response($location){
  if (isset($_POST['status_response'])) {
    $location = esc_url_raw(add_query_arg('status_response', $_POST['status_response'], $location));
  }
  return $location;
}
add_filter('redirect_post_location', 'pass_status_response');
```

Finally, I append that value to the messages in `post_updated_messages`.

```
function add_status_message($messages) {
  if ($_GET['status_response']) {
    $post = get_post();
    $post_type = get_post_type($post);
    foreach ($messages[$post_type] as &$msg) {
      $msg = $msg . 'Status: ' . $_GET['status_response'];
    }
  }
  return $messages;
}
add_filter('post_updated_messages', 'add_status_message');
```

This appears to work fairly well, however, it's very experimental. If anyone has any feedback on how I could improve this solution, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get the same result what you are looking for with filter hook `post_updated_messages`. You just need the post id for the confirmation thing that you are doing which you can do over here as well using `$_GET['post']` which contains your post id.

Here is function which will do the thing.

```
function your_modified_message( $messages ){

    if(isset($_GET['post'])){

        $post_id = $_GET['post'];

        // get your response for respective post_id 
        $response = ping_other_service_and_get_confirmation($post_id);
        syslog(LOG_INFO, 'Response:' . $response['body']);

        // get your information concatenated with update post message in next line
        $messages['post'][1] = $messages['post'][1] . '<br>' . $response['body'];

        return $messages;

    } else {

        return $messages;

    }

}
// using filter hook to modify your message
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'your_modified_message',10,1);
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks. That would work for the messages, but I need to call the `ping_other_service_and_get_confirmation()` function on the `post_updated`action (and only on that action). I just need to pass the response over to the `post_updated_messages` filter.

Comment: Glad to know that you were able to find some solution on your own.